# Parse-Server email verification process

Tags: node.js, authentication, parse-server, user-accounts, email-verification

When using Parse-Server with an iOS app.
It is possible to implement user-account email verification.

What is needed to have the user receive the email message so that she/he can verify her/his email address?

At this point I have the password reset feature working, but the user does not receive any verification message. So I must be missing something. Actually the only thing I did relating to email verification is adding the line:

```
  verifyUserEmails: true,
```

to my index.js file. So the relevant code now looks like:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  .........
  serverURL: "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse",
  publicServerURL: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse',
  appName: 'MyApp',
  .........
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailAdapter: {
    module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'sending-adr@fmail.cor',
      domain: 'dmain.net',
      apiKey: process.env.EML_ADAPTER_KEY
    }
  }
});
```

And further down the workflow, I presume there must be some ways to customize the verification mail sent to the user.

Comment: Can you please try also to add `publicServerURL`?

Comment: I already have publicServerURL. I edited the post to show it.

Comment: Do you see any error in your Parse Server logs? If you go to your malign dashboard, do you see any email arriving over there?

Comment: Also... are you filling out user email when signing them up?

Comment: Thanks. I just posted my solution as an answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up by solving the problem.

Inside the bloc of code:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  .....
});
```

after this sub-bloc:

```
  emailAdapter: {
    module: '@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter',
    .....
    options: {.....}
  }
```

I added this one:

```
   customPages: {
    invalidLink: '.....',
    verifyEmailSuccess: '.....',
    choosePassword: '.....',
    passwordResetSuccess: '.....'
  }
```

From that point it all started to work as expected.